# Can't get emacs server to start with X11

Tags: emacs

I'm confused how emacs server is supposed to work. I would have thought, if the DISPLAY environment variable is set, the emacs server would start an X frame when it has a file to edit, but not so.

So if I run `emacs --daemon` and then run `emacsclient foo.x` it starts a terminal emacs session. But if I kill that daemon and run `emacs &` (opens X11 frame) followed by `M-x server-start` and `emacsclient foo.x` then it opens foo.x in the X11 session.

How to run a server daemon from the command line so that it is X11 based?

Comment: That seems odd.  Can you confirm that you are testing all four of those shell commands (the 'bad' pair, and the 'good' pair) from a single terminal and shell?

Comment: Yes, a single terminal. Of course I ps aux, and kill the daemon before the 2nd scenario. WHen I run emacs -daemon with an active X11 session, should I expect a window to open then, or only after I use emacsclient?

Answer (score 5):

I find Emacs client interface a bit complicated from the user perspective. But with some effort, I learned how to use it.

`emacsclient <file>` opens the file in the last created frame, which could be an X frame of a terminal frame. If there is no visible frame, it creates a terminal frame. (This is at least on Linux. On Windows it is a little bit different, which I won't go into details here).

You can instead use `emacsclient -c <file>` which creates a new X frame and opens the file in the newly created frame. Note that this command waits for you finish editing the file to return. If you want the command to return immediately, use `emacsclient -c -n <file>`.

I mostly use the following commands to open files with Emacs client (I in fact created [a wrapper script](https://github.com/canaknesil/linux-configuration/blob/master/bin/start-emacs) just to be able to start open files with Emacs from command-line with less effort):

`emacsclient -a "" -nw [files...]` : New Emacs client frame in terminal, optionally with some files opened. Here `-a ""` starts the server if it is not already running.

`emacsclient -a "" -c -n [files...]` : New Emacs client frame in X, optionally with some files opened. Return immediately.

`emacsclient -a "" -n files...` : Open files in the last created frame. Return immediately.

Comment: Huh, I could have sworn that `-c` wasn't necessary to get a GUI frame unless no file arguments were given, but you're absolutely right -- plain `emacsclient <file>` can open in the terminal even when GUI frames are supported.

Comment: That certainly helps. I think I remember from the distant past -c -n and -w, but forgot about it. So it sounds like the only way an emacs --daemon could have a visible X11 frame, is if you used emacsclient -c at some point.

Comment: Actually I still can't figure out how to do what I want to do. What I want is that if there's an X11 frame open, use it. If there's not, create one. emacsclient -c is no good because it always creates a new frame. I guess I could try and use xwininfo to try and figure it out, but it's a nasty hack.

Comment: I'm doing this now, but it's quite ugly....   if ! xwininfo -tree -root | grep " - GNU Emacs at " >/dev/null  ; then  FRAME=-c  fi   ; emacsclient  $FRAME -n $FILE

Comment: @xpusostomos I am actually doing what you want (openning files in the existing frame, creating new frame if necessary) in the [wrapper script](https://github.com/canaknesil/linux-configuration/blob/master/bin/start-emacs) that I attached. I am running `n_frames=$(emacsclient -e '(seq-length (frame-list))' 2>/dev/null)`. `n_frames` is empty, 1, or 2, if server is not running, running but no frames were made (except for the server frame which is hidden), or running and there is at least one visible frame, respectively. Depending on this number, I am executing the appropriate command.

Comment: @xpusostomos try emacsclient -r <file> perhaps?

Comment: @C.Aknesil thanks for that, it's a bit cleaner than my solution.

Comment: @C.Aknesil Actually, that doesn't work because  n_frames counts terminal frames. So if I have a number of terminal tabs, some of which are running terminal emacs, I don't want that to count. I might open some terminal emacs for some quick edit jobs, but have an X11 emacs for more serious editing sessions. So if I want a particular file openning in X11 emacs, I don't want any quick edits I have open in random terminals to count like X11 frames.

Comment: You can inspect and filter `frame-list`.  E.g.: `(length (delq nil (mapcar (lambda (f) (display-graphic-p f)) (frame-list))))`

Answer (score 0):

Use `emacsclient -c <file>` to open a file in a new emacs frame.

Use `emacsclient -r <file2>` to open the second file in the same emacs frame

Comment: No, because what I'm looking for is to open a frame if none exists, and if none exists, -r gives you a terminal editor.